# PHP Content Disposition file name error

Tags: php, filenames, content-disposition

I have a database from which I would like the user to download data as a csv file. The user has the option to choose the range of data to be downloaded - namely selected date to current date. I want the csv file to be named as 'selected-date.csv'

I used the following code:

```
$filename = $date . "csv";
header ('Content-Type:text/csv'); 
header ('Content-Dispostion: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
```

The file is downloaded but with the PHP file name(get.php) in which this code resides. I have also tried giving a default file name like "download.csv" but that doesn't work either. No matter what I do the file is downloaded with the php file's name. This is across Chrome, Firefox and IE. I don't have Safari to try it on. The date is in the format YYYY-MM-DD. So I don't think there are any invalid characters that can set off any error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does your packet sniffer say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set headers for file download

```
downloadfile($filename) {
    $now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
    header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
    header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");

    // force download  
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
}

//file name 
$filename = date("Y-m-d") . ".csv"; // make sure it is .csv ( i can not see . in your case )

//call function
downloadfile($filename);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Parveen! This renamed the file successfully but it only gave me the current date. I was able to successfully modify it to the date the user selects.

Comment: Hi, You just need to change date("Y-m-d", strtotime($userdate) ); where you can take $userdate as any input date from user.